# spark ssc.textFileStream is not streamining any files from directory

Tags: filesystems, apache-spark, spark-streaming, data-stream

I am trying to execute below code using eclipse (with maven conf) with 2 worker and each have 2 core or also tried with spark-submit.

```
public class StreamingWorkCount implements Serializable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Logger.getLogger("org.apache.spark").setLevel(Level.WARN);
        JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(
                "spark://192.168.1.19:7077", "JavaWordCount",
                new Duration(1000));
        JavaDStream<String> trainingData = jssc.textFileStream(
                "/home/bdi-user/kaushal-drive/spark/data/training").cache();
        trainingData.foreach(new Function<JavaRDD<String>, Void>() {

            public Void call(JavaRDD<String> rdd) throws Exception {
                List<String> output = rdd.collect();
                System.out.println("Sentences Collected from files " + output);
                return null;
            }
        });

        trainingData.print();
        jssc.start();
        jssc.awaitTermination();
    }
}
```

And log of that code

```
15/01/22 21:57:13 INFO FileInputDStream: New files at time 1421944033000 ms:

15/01/22 21:57:13 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1421944033000 ms
15/01/22 21:57:13 INFO JobScheduler: Starting job streaming job 1421944033000 ms.0 from job set of time 1421944033000 ms
15/01/22 21:57:13 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: foreach at StreamingKMean.java:33
15/01/22 21:57:13 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 3 finished: foreach at StreamingKMean.java:33, took 0.000094 s
Sentences Collected from files []
-------------------------------------------
15/01/22 21:57:13 INFO JobScheduler: Finished job streaming job 1421944033000 ms.0 from job set of time 1421944033000 ms
Time: 1421944033000 ms
-------------------------------------------15/01/22 21:57:13 INFO JobScheduler: Starting job streaming job 1421944033000 ms.1 from job set of time 1421944033000 ms


15/01/22 21:57:13 INFO JobScheduler: Finished job streaming job 1421944033000 ms.1 from job set of time 1421944033000 ms
15/01/22 21:57:13 INFO JobScheduler: Total delay: 0.028 s for time 1421944033000 ms (execution: 0.013 s)
15/01/22 21:57:13 INFO MappedRDD: Removing RDD 5 from persistence list
15/01/22 21:57:13 INFO BlockManager: Removing RDD 5
15/01/22 21:57:13 INFO FileInputDStream: Cleared 0 old files that were older than 1421943973000 ms: 
15/01/22 21:57:13 INFO FileInputDStream: Cleared 0 old files that were older than 1421943973000 ms: 
15/01/22 21:57:13 INFO ReceivedBlockTracker: Deleting batches ArrayBuffer()
```

The Problem is that, i am not getting data form the file which is in the directory. Please help me.

Comment: Facing exactly same issue on windows machine. Please suggest

Comment: I think this only work in HDFS and not on local file system

Comment: see also this question (and answer): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704326/spark-filestreaming-issue

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try it with another directory and then copy these files to that directory, while the job is running.

Comment: yes, i have also tried that with another dir. i didn't understand what is the problem and how to debug, even which is not showing in log.

Comment: But was the directory empty when you started the job?

Comment: Actually some files are already there and i also copy some files when i start my job.

Comment: Is this HDFS directory or a local one?

Comment: It should be HDFS and you should copy files in it while the program is running

Comment: you mean that dir should be empty at the starting and when i start my job, copied into hdfs .

Comment: yes, @pzecevic your are right. Spark processed only those files that copied into HDFS after the job execution, it is not read previous files that are in directory.

Answer (score 6):

had the same problem.
Here is my code:

> lines = jssc.textFileStream("file:///Users/projects/spark/test/data');

the TextFileSTream is *very* sensitive; what i ended up doing was:

```
1. Run Spark program
2. touch datafile
3. mv datafile datafile2
4. mv datafile2  /Users/projects/spark/test/data
```

and that did it.

Comment: I am using windows lines = jssc.textFileStream("file:///c:/data');    lines.foreachRDD(file=> {
      
      file.foreach(fc=> {
        println(fc)
      })
    })
I am not getting output. how to do resolve this ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to add the scheme, i.e. `file://` or `hdfs://` in front of your path.

---

*Undoing the edit to my comment because:* It is in fact `file://` and `hdfs://` which needs to be added "in front of" the path, so the total path becomes `file:///tmp/file.txt` or `hdfs:///user/data`. If there is no NameNode set in the configuration, the latter needs to be `hdfs://host:port/user/data`.

Comment: using HDFS, it works but when i use local file system with 'file:///'(spark does not support file://) prefix, it is not working.

Comment: That may be because you are using a cluster and the path specified must be accessible by all Spark executors, i.e. it is not enough if the Spark driver can access it.

Answer (score 0):

JavaDoc suggests  function only streams new files.

Ref:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.0.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/streaming/api/java/JavaStreamingContext.html#textFileStream(java.lang.String)

Create an input stream that monitors a Hadoop-compatible filesystem for new files and reads them as text files (using key as LongWritable, value as Text and input format as TextInputFormat). Files must be written to the monitored directory by "moving" them from another location within the same file system. File names starting with . are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

`textFileStream` can only monitor a folder when the files in the folder are being **added** or **updated**.

If you just want to read files, you can rather use `SparkContext.textFile`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to take in count that Spark Streaming will only read the new files in the directory, no the updated ones (once they are in the directory) and also they all must have the same format.

[Source](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#basic-sources)

Answer (score 0):

I've bee scratching my head for hours, and what worked for me is

- The answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/33030590/1170677
- I forgot to start the streaming process so you need to `ssc.start()`